# PHP Interpreter is not Installed (Linux)

Tags: php, linux, phpstorm, interpreter

I am using PhpStorm on Linux Mint 16.  I created a Hello World, but am struggling to run it.  I am getting an error "PHP Interpreter is not installed. Press 'Fix' to edit your project configuration."

[image]

When I hit "Fix", I get:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this?  There are no Interpreter options.

Comment: Can you run **php -v** in the console?

Comment: PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:24:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2013, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should install PHP. Your IDE is not responsible for that, you need to do it yourself.

See this site for instructions: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486

**Update:**
Add PHP interpreter following: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/enabling-php-support.html

PHP home could be set to /usr/bin on linux.

Comment: This did not resolve the problem.  Some of it said the stuff was obsolete when I tried to download it.  I think this (2 year old solution) is no longer valid.

Comment: Also, I have already installed PHP (but did attempt to reinstall with those instructions).

Comment: @Evorlor Well, I'm not familiar with mint. I always used RedHat or CentOS. The package names might changed, but it's about just the same steps.

Comment: @Evorlor Maybe you can configure the interpreter path manually.

Comment: By any chance do you know what that path would be?

Comment: @Evorlor Try executing **whereis php**

Comment: php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/X11/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz was the output, yet none of those are options while searching for an interpreter path.  When I used usr/bin/X11, it just came up empty.

Comment: @Evorlor I've seen people just put /usr/bin in the PHPHome field when adding a interpreter, have you tried that？

Comment: Still no interpreter there. :-/

Comment: @Evorlor This is weird. I was able to discover an installed interpreter when *adding* an interpreter with PHP Home set as /usr/bin. That's all I can help, your issue seems quite strange to me.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help!  I came across this tutorial which helped out.  We were barely off.  Thanks for your time!  You are awesoME!  https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/enabling-php-support.html  (Post this link in your answer please.)

Answer (score 3):

i did this 
`sudo apt-get install php5-dev
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi`

then add interpreter and php was under the  /usr/bin